# Java: create a bytearray-backed FileChannel

Tags: java, testing, file-io, io, nio

I have a class for IO that uses ByteBuffer to buffer access to a FileChannel (so it basically accepts a FileChannel at the constructor). I'd like to unittest it, so it'd be nice if I could get a bytearray-backed FileChannel to avoid creating and deleting files during test.

To get you an idea, it'd be perfect if I could get something like ByteArrayOutputStream.getChannel().

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Channels.newChannel(InputStream)` or `Channels.newChannel(OutputStream)` but those will give you a `ReadableByteChannel` or a `WritableByteChannel`. They won't give you a `FileChannel`, which makes sense given that you don't have a file - a `FileChannel` without a file doesn't make any sense. If you change your class to accept any `ReadableByteChannel` or `WritableByteChannel`, that should be fine.